# Facebook OAuth failing after Ajax / HistoryAPI page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, oauth

Time to reach out for some help! I have a site for which I am using Ajax and HistoryAPI for transitions between pages. This includes an integration with Facebook's OAuth API to populate short data capture forms for customers. This works great when visiting a page without the Ajax loading i.e. first visit or page refresh.

But the Facebook integration is failing when I try it following an Ajax page load. When Facebook's dialogue box appears, it is blank and doesn't disappear. Using console.log I can see the position response from the API when I click the close button on the dialogue box. I can also see the userID and access_token returned when I close the dialogue box (visible via console.log).

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
  functionThree();
  historyAPI();
});

function historyAPI() {
  String.prototype.decodeHTML = function() {
    return $("<div>", {html: "" + this}).html();
  };

  var $main = $("main"),

  init = function(href) {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();
  },

  ajaxLoad = function(html) {
    document.title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1].trim().decodeHTML();
    init();
  },

  loadPage = function(href) {
    $main.load(href + ' main>*', ajaxLoad);
    $('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: 0});
  };

  init();

  $(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
      loadPage(location.href);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'nav a', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('main').fadeOut(250);

    if (href.indexOf(document.domain) > -1 || href.indexOf(':') === -1) {
      history.pushState({}, '', href);
      loadPage(href);
      return false;
    }
  });
}

functionOne {
  // ...
}
functionTwo {
  // ...
}
functionThree {
  // ...
}
```

And my Facebook OAuth integration is handled by the following in a separate file:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  } else {}
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId   : 9999999999999999,
    cookie    : true,
    status    : true,
    xfbml   : true,
    version   : 'v2.1'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fb_login(){
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log(response);
      access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
        var firstNameInput = document.getElementById("firstName");
        var lastNameInput = document.getElementById("lastName");
        emailInput.placeholder = response.email;
        emailInput.value = response.email;
        firstNameInput.placeholder = response.first_name;
        firstNameInput.value = response.first_name;
        lastNameInput.placeholder = response.last_name;
        lastNameInput.value = response.last_name;
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
      });

    } else {
      console.log('User cancelled Facebook login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
  }, {
      scope: 'publish_stream,email'
  });
}
```

My Ajax loading is targeting the `main` within my page and replacing the contents of that only. My JS and Facebook specific JS is sitting outside of this.

Any help would be much appreciated. As I say, it is working fine with a normal page load, but for some reason it cannot work following an Ajax page load. I have been hunting for methods to reset / restart the OAuth methods but no joy so far.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a working code snippet so one can have a look?

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried to load page with ajax and open fb login dialog, and I cannot reproduce the error you saw. It's work properly in my environment. So my suggestion would be first checking if there's any error log caused by your js code, then try to strip down your code and give the most simple way to replicate your problem. Also please tell me which Browser you are using to see the error. Thanks

Comment: Hi Tim, are you sure about this? "Using console.log I can see the position response from the API when I click the close button on the dialogue box. I can also see the userID and access_token returned when I close the dialogue box (visible via console.log)." If the user doesn't accept your App, you'll never get back an access token, can you please double check this? Would you mind please provide a link where we can reproduce the error? Please also check the URL used when the dialog appears blank, that could give you some hints about what might be going on.

Comment: Resolution for my issue here - for anyone coming across this post in the future...

If it doesn't exist, Facebook's JS will insert an empty div called <div class="fb-root"></div> into which they will dump a bunch of stuff. If it does exist, it doesn't need to add this to your DOM and so it doesn't. My issue was that I had this in my DOM but it was inside the AJAX'ed content so it wasn't read properly on each page transition. If I left it to FB to create this DOM element, it would add it inside the AJAX'ed content too. My fix was simply to manually add this element outside the AJAX'ed content.